# Most stage wins without a Tour de France title

Tags: tour-de-france

does anyone know who won the most stages in a single Tour de France without winning the overall race in the same year?

The most common question I see is, who won the Tour de France without winning a single stage but my question is the opposite.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

A bit of searching turns up a tie.  In the [1930 Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_Tour_de_France) [Charles Pélissier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_P%C3%A9lissier) won 8 stages but the overall winner was [André Leducq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Leducq) who only won 2 individual stages.  In the [1976 Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Tour_de_France) [Freddy Maertens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddy_Maertens) won 8 stages but the overall winner was [Lucien Van Impe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Van_Impe).

The only other cyclist to have won 8 stages in a single tour was, naturally, [Eddie Merckx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_Merckx) in the [1970 Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Tour_de_France) but in that case he, also naturally, won the overall.

Comment: It's not a tie if either Pelissier or Maertens had the most days in the yellow jersey.

Comment: @Christine The question isn't about days in yellow, it's simply about stage wins.

Comment: @Christine To actually answer your question instead of dismissing it as out of scope: Charles Pélissier only was in the yellow jersey for 1 stage. Freddy Maertens was in the yellow jersey for 10 stages, though a number of those were half-stages. He also wore the green jersey for the entire Tour, so depending on how you interpret "winning the tour", he may not count.